# X11 apps do not scale well on 4k displays

Tags: xorg, 4k-monitor, hdpi

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 15 with 4K touchscreen display, I was able to set up the laptop's screen resolution to the native 3840x2160, and setting "*Scale for menu and title bars*" to 2 allowed for a very nice visual experience.

One of the default apps though, Ubuntu Web Browser, didn't seem to take into account the 2x factor and its fonts and icons still appeared too tiny to be usable. I didn't care as Firefox is my to go browser, and I simply forgot about it.

Today I wanted to give a try to Xfe as an interesting alternative to the stock Nautilus, and noticed the same problem: the app window content is too small to be used at 3840x2160. Peering around I've noticed this problem affects all X11 applications, to name a few:

- Ubuntu Web Browser
- XTerm
- UXTerm
- X File Image
- X File Package
- X File Writer

Is there any fix or workaround to this?